# Field 'Passport_Number__pc' cannot be filtered in a query call

Tags: apex, soql, filters

This might be a basic question.

My SOQL is failing in Prod:

```
[SELECT Id, Subject FROM Case WHERE Account.Passport_Number__pc =: value]
```

> Field 'Passport_Number__pc' cannot be filtered in a  query call

This field on Account and Contact is set to `isFilterable = false`

In UAT:

The query doesn't fail in UAT.

This field on Account and Contact is set to `isFilterable = true`

What could explain the discrepancy in isFilterable value between UAT and Prod?

**Please note: The field is not encrypted in UAT and Prod.**

**Update on 5/03/2024**

**Salesforce recommended we deploy the fields from UAT to Prod (not sure if this will fix it) - They didn't explain the discrepancy.**

Comment: Do you use Platform Shield (have it enabled on some orgs) and is the `Passport_Number__pc` field encrypted? If so, this is probably why you cannot use it in a SOQL `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The field is not encrypted. @PhilW

Comment: I don't mean "Text (Encrypted)" as the field data type, I mean has it been set up for encryption at rest with Platform Shield?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled in UAT and Prod @PhilW

Comment: I do not understand. 1. Is platform shield enabled on the org? 2. Is the field configured to be encrypted at rest by Shield? Only if both are true will the field be unfilterable.

Comment: 1. Yes 2. No. - That is why it's puzzling.

Comment: Strange.  Do you have other custom Person Account fields in production with `filterable = false`, but it is true in sandbox?  Is your sandbox on the exact same SF release as production (check status.salesforce.com)?

Comment: Both UAT and Prod are on the same release version (Spring' 24 Patch 10.11). Yes, we have other custom fields on Person Account e.g. Id_Number__pc `filterable = false` in Prod but true in UAT and other sandboxes. We are talking to Salesforce soon and will update you all once we have any info. I'm assuming there is no way to update the `filterable` property. @DavidCheng

Comment: Updated my question @DavidCheng